# PacketProcessingListener implementation error

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to implement **"PacketProcessingListener"**. When I run `mvn clean install` I am getting the following error in Project features.
I did not change any thing in the feature folder.

```
Results :
Tests in error: 
Can't install feature odl-qos/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:   
Could not start bundle mvn:org.opendaylight.qos/qos-impl/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT in feature(s) odl-qos-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: The bundle "org.opendaylight.qos.impl_0.1.0.SNAPSHOT [291]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.packet.service.rev130709; version="[0.4.0,1.0.0)"
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Reactor Summary:

[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-api ............. SUCCESS [ 10.049 s]

[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-impl ............ SUCCESS [  5.353 s]

[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-cli ............. SUCCESS [  3.468 s]

[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-features ........ FAILURE [01:31 min]

[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-karaf ........... SKIPPED

[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-artifacts ....... SKIPPED

[INFO] ODL :: org.opendaylight.qos :: qos-it .............. SKIPPED

[INFO] qos 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT ................................. SKIPPED

**************************
```

**can an error in the implementation folder affect the feature folder?**
I added the following dependency to my implementation folder pom.xml

```
**<dependency>
   <groupId>org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.model</groupId>
    <artifactId>model-flow-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.3-Carbon</version>
</dependency>**
```

My imp-blueprint looks contains:

```
 reference id="dataBroker" interface="org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.binding.api.DataBroker"  odl:type="default" />
reference id="rpcRegistry" interface="org.opendaylight.controller.sal.binding.api.RpcProviderRegistry"/>

reference id="notificationService" interface="org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.binding.api.NotificationPublishService"/>

reference id="notificationProviderService" interface="org.opendaylight.controller.sal.binding.api.NotificationProviderService" />

bean id="provider"
    class="org.opendaylight.qos.impl.QosProvider"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <argument ref="dataBroker" />
    <argument ref="rpcRegistry" />
    <argument ref="notificationService" />
    <argument ref="notificationProviderService" />
    <argument ref="packetHandlerService" />
  </bean>

odl:rpc-service id="packetHandlerService"
interface="org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.packet.service.rev130709.PacketProcessingService" />

odl:notification-listener ref="provider"/>**
```

I am using -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.3-carbon for building my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broken features build seems to be due to using old released archetypeVersion=1.3.0-Carbon.
just changing the -DarchetypeVersion=1.5.0-SNAPSHOT or -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.0 fixed the problem